# Scale OpenTelemetry collector for metrics

Tags: open-telemetry

I was having a look at the official docs on the [loadbalancer exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/exporter/loadbalancingexporter/README.md) and I realized that only `traces` and `logs` are supported.

I'm trying to understand why is that:

1. because the project is not mature enough so it doesn't have a `metrics` pipeline (not yet done)
2. because it doesn't make sense to horizontally scale for metrics
3. something else

Which one is it? Can somebody shed some light on this?

We're planning to use OTel for both metrics and traces. I wonder if it makes sense to have Prometheus scrape the metrics from the LoadBalancer (Gateway) and then have the other collectors (the ones behind the LoadBalancer) just get the traces.

Alternatively we could use sidecars but sidecars are a 1-to-1 with the pod and they get restarted with it. We were looking for something more resilient and that is independent from the services that will send the metrics/traces.

Comment: IMHO you are mixing concept of receivers and exporters. You don't need loadbalancer EXPORTER to have metrics from loadbalancer. Are you really sure that you need loadbalancer EXPORTER?

Comment: @JanGaraj I will be sending both traces and metrics so I do need the loadbalancer exporter to balance traces based on a route ID.

Comment: where you will save a route ID in the metric?

Comment: @JanGaraj I won't. Metrics are stateless, right? So only traces will be balanced via a route ID, not metrics. But I still have to send them both. I think I might have a solution, if it works I'll update here with an answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. You want to use loadbalancer exporter for metrics = to spread metrics accros multiple backends, but you don't have a route key to identify which backend should be used for routing.

Comment: I don't need a routing key for metrics, labels are enough. They are stateless so I can't just spread them, Prometheus will do the rest. For traces though a route ID is needed and for that I'll be using a loadbalancer exporter. Meaning you can have 1 collector with the loadbalancer exporter pointing to a headless svc which resolves to any number of pods running other collectors. you can send traces to the 1st collector with the LB exporter and send the metrics to the headless svc. Why it doesn't make sense? That's what I'm going to try anyway and update here with the results.

Comment: You really don't need (beta) loadbalancer exporter. It is doing very naive loadbalancing. I would rather expose set of other collector behind standard LB as a service (e.g. AWS ALB). Standard LB is doing healthchecks, it can loadbalance based on the backend load, ...